# Linking to a Library requires MFC80U.LIB

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2008, mfc, linker, sketchup

I am trying to compile the SkpWriter example from the latest SketchUp C++ SDK. However, the linker gives me LNK1104 saying that "mfc80u.lib" could not be found since one of the static libraries (Utils.lib) in the SDK depends on some MFC 8 libraries. I am using VS2008 and only mfc90u.lib is available.

Is there a way to use mfc90u.lib in place of mfc80u.lib (anything short of renaming the file)?
Are MFC 8 DLLs and LIBs available for download? (Why should someone using a DLL created with VS2005 also be expected to install VS2005?!!) What are my options here?

Answer (score 1):

Right-click your project, Properties, Linker, Input.  In the "Ignore Specific Library" setting put mfc80u.lib.  In the "Additional Dependencies" setting add mfc90u.lib

No guarantee that this will work but you got a decent shot at it.  Your best bet is to contact the SDK vendor and ask for an update.

Comment: The SDK vendor (a company called Google) is not very interested in supporting this particular SDK since it's given away for free.

Comment: Hmya, free software is only free if your time isn't worth anything.  How did changing the settings work out?

Comment: Not too well. VS wouldn't copy mfc90u.dll to the output folder. I had to do that manually... followed by issues with msvcr90.dll.

Comment: What part of "no guarantee that this will work" is unclear to you?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you have 2 option:
1. Build your exe in VS2005 and use existing dll.
2. Rebuilt your dll in VS2008 and link with your exe.

MFC6 & MFC9 binary is not compatible, especially CString and CWnd, they are different in VC6 and VC9....

Comment: Something might be useful:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2339759/why-visual-c-6-complains-on-private-destructor