# Why/How does the mechanism that cleans up statics, gain access rights that allow it to call private members?

Tags: c++, singleton, destructor, access-modifiers

I tested a pattern for declaring a singleton class in C++ that makes the default **destructor** 'private', but the pattern makes no use of this destructor through any member call.

I tested this code on Ubuntu QQ using the gnu g++ compliler - the destructor was called on program termination, although designated 'private'.

Who/What/How is this destructor called, since it's designated private?

*Note: I am coming from the Delphi/Object Pascal world, and there is no static class declaration supported by ObjectPascal - although there are several ways to create a singleton. In my experience, 'private'('strict private'...) is **PRIVATE**. I see that in C++ it is not quite that way.*

**Explanation?**

Comment: possible duplicate of [How are the private destructors of static objects called?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524131/how-are-the-private-destructors-of-static-objects-called)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**(Edited after OP edit)**

Making the destructor private prevents it from being called explicitly.

If the destructor were public, this would be legal:

```
 MyClass.getInstance().~MyClass();
```

The destructors of static storage objects are called as a result of returning from main() or calling exit().

Comment: @Mikey - The new question is answered above.

Comment: See new question title and edit... :-) I guess I wasn't making my question clear enough

Comment: You asked if it should be public. The second question is addressed by http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11524131/how-are-the-private-destructors-of-static-objects-called .

Comment: OK - I see over there what someone quoted from the standard - according to that, the answer is YES, the mechanism that cleans up statics is not restricted by access modifiers. I can easily test this as well... let's see what else comes up here - I have no problem giving you the credit.

Answer (score 4):

The object is typically instantiated by a `static` member function called something like `getInstance`, which then gives you a reference to the object. Because it's a member function, it has access to the constructor.

The classic example:

```
class S
{
    public:
        // This is a member function so can access the constructor of S
        static S& getInstance()
        {
            static S    instance;
            return instance;
        }
    private:
        S() {};
        S(S const&);
        void operator=(S const&);
};
```

Comment: Obvious - dumb question on my part re constructors - see edit.

Answer (score 1):

Typical singleton classes have a static member function that returns a pointer to the singleton object. For example:

```
Singleton *Singleton::instance();
```

where `instance()` is a static member function. The static member function can call private constructors.

Comment: Obvious - dumb question on my part re constructors - see edit.

Comment: If I am not mistaken, the destructor of static objects is called when the program terminates.

Comment: So I would think - but what's calling it? If destructor is private, it can't be called by anything external. And if the default destructor will get called anyhow, what's the point of declaring it private? And what if you have cleanup code in your destructor? I think something is not right with this design.

Comment: I have never used this particular idiom myself (singletons with private destructors), so I can't vouch for its effectiveness. The point of declaring the destructor private is simple though: this ensures no user can ever destroy the singleton object. If the destructor is not private, anyone could destroy the singleton through `delete Singleton::instance();`

Comment: 'anyone could destroy the singleton' - understood. See new question title and edit... :-) I guess I wasn't making my question clear enough.

Answer (score 1):

They are private because you don't want to allow construction or destruction of that object by any code outside. Singletons generally have a static instance that is initialized and deleted via factory methods.

```
tempalte <class T>
class Singleton
{
public:
    static T* GetInstance()
    {
        if(!m_sInstance)
        {
            m_sInstance = new T();
        }

        return m_sInstance;
    }

    static void DestroyInstance()
    {
        delete m_sInstance;
        m_sInstance = 0;
    }
private:
    static T* m_sInstance;    
};

class Foo : public Singleton<Foo>
{
friend class Singleton<Foo>;
private:
    Foo();
    ~Foo();
};
```

So you can call `Foo::GetInstance()` and `Foo::DestroyInstance()` to access and delete the singleton object.